# Present subclassed view controller from another view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, subclass, viewcontroller

I have some problems to use subclasses in Swift, hope someone can help me.

### What I have

Two view controllers:

**VC1** with just some UIButtons

**EffectVC** that do some animation depending on the button pressed on VC1

```
import UIKit

protocol viewAnimation {
    func initialStateSet()
    func finalStateSet()
}

class EffectVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.initialStateSet()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.finalStateSet()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func initialStateSet() {
    }

    func finalStateSet() {
    }
}

class GrowingEffect : EffectVC, viewAnimation {

    override func initialStateSet() {
        // some stuff
    }

    override func finalStateSet() {
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

### The problem

Maybe a simple question but I can't do what I want in Swift: I need to set a subclass according to the button that is pressed.

In other words I need to present subclassed view controller from my VC1 according to which button is pressed on VC1.

If I press the **first button** for example I want to **show the VC 2 with the class GrowingEffect** for use some custom stuff (this stuff must change according to the selected button).

### What I tried

1. use IBAction for create my subclassed VC2 and show it

   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

   let destinationViewController : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EffectVC") as! GrowingEffect

   self.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

but I got

> Could not cast value of type 'ViewAnimationDemo.EffectVC'
>   (0x109948570) to 'ViewAnimationDemo.GrowingEffect' (0x109948650).

2. use PrepareForSegue

but I can't set any subclass

## What I really want to do

I know there are some other solution, like not using storyboard, but now I describe exactly what I want to do, hoping this is possibile:

**have only one view controller in IB (EffectVC) associate with the class EffectVC. The class EffectVC has some subclasses like GrowingEffect.**

In my code I want to instantiate the view controller EffectVC with the subclass that I need: for example **instantiate the view controller in IB EffectVC with the class GrowingEffect**.

I know that if I have one view controller for every subclass of EffectVC I can do what I want but I don't want so many view controller in IB because they are equal, the only things that I want to change are 2 methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some things mixed up in your setup. You should have 2 view controllers, each set up in its file, and each present in the storyboard with its identifier. It is ok if `GrowingEffect` inherits from `EffectVC`.

What you currently do with `as! GrowingEffect` is actually trying to cast the `UIViewController` instance you get from calling `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EffectVC")` to `GrowingEffect`. This will not work, because it is of type `EffectVC`.

Rather, you need to call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EffectVC")` if button X is pressed, and `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GrowingEffect")` if button Y is pressed.

**EDIT**

If you use storyboard, you have to instantiate view controllers using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. But you can only get an instance of `GrowingEffect`, if it is present on the storyboard.

It is not possible to "cast" an instance of `EffectVC` to `GrowingEffect` once created.

So, you have two possibilities here:

1. Use storyboard and put both view controllers on it. Use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to instantiate the view controller you need, depending on the button pressed.
2. Do not use storyboard. Then you can create the needed view controller manually and use your `UINavigationController`'s `pushViewController` method to present it.

Comment: ok I know this solution but I need to set up in Interface Builder 2 view controller...there's no solution for use one parent class with subclasses and one view controller in IB?

Comment: You can also create an instance of the subclass and present it manually. I.e. if you want, you don't need to use storyboard alltogether.

Comment: uhm I know I can do this stuff only by code but now I update the question witch really I want to do, maybe I'm not so clear

Comment: thank you so much! I had doubts about the various solutions but now all is clear :) I'm evaluating a third solution, use a property and do stuff according to its value. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: @MassimoPolimeni Can you post your third solution as an answer here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast from parent class to child class, parent class just doesn't have the capacity to know what the child is doing.  You can however cast from a child to parent, so you would want to set your view controller as GrowingEffect, then cast it to Effect, but again there is no strong suit to doing this either unless some method needs the parent class and you are using the child class.  It looks like you need a redesign of how you want your view controllers laid out.  Now I am assuming you have 2 children, lets call GrowingEffect and ShrinkingEffect.  In your designer, you set your 1 to GrowingEffect and the other to ShrinkingEffect and make sure they have unique identifiers.  Then you can use your view to present an Effect, and pass in either of those objects.

Comment: ok I know this solution but I need to set up in Interface Builder 2 view controller...there's no solution for use one parent class with subclasses and one view controller in IB?

Comment: you could set it up to where the view controller in the story board is the parent, then when presenting the view controller, you grab the parent from the story board, then create a new child object based on the parent, and present that view instead

 `let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Effect");

 let childvc = GlowingEffect(viewController: vc)
 currentViewController.presentViewController(childvc, animated:true, completion:nil);`

Of course you are going to have to implement NSCoding methods to create the copying.